# findandmodify search 2 ID in collection and add a push Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

an array in both, only it works I join the other not. I work this way. there any way to fix this inconvenience?

```
    collection:findAndModify({
            query: {
                $in: [req.user._id, idunique]
            },
            update: {
                $push: {
                    Amigos: {
                        usuario: idUserAccept,
                        name: fotoUserAccept,
                        img: fotoUserAccept
                    }
                }
            },
            new: true
        }).success(function(doc){
            res.json(doc);
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

seem that you have mistake about query syntax.

```
findAndModify is Deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate instead
```

check document in [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: use updateMany if you want to multiple update  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#updateMany